# Tkinter window not opened

Tags: python, tkinter

My tkinter window not opened after i add while true function. How can I get this to work. Its works without while true, but i need it in my function.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import random
import sys
import random



maxcount = int (input("How many times "))
i = 1
cats = Tk()
cats.wm_title("maxcount test")
cats.geometry("500x500")

def black():
    while True:
        i+1
        if i == 5:
            break

Button(cats, text="Start", command=black()).grid(row=1, column=0)


Label(cats, text="How many times:").grid(row=0, column=0)

cats.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to have the `while` loop? At the moment all you are doing is setting a variable to equal 5, this doesn't *need* a `while` loop to do. Is there something you are omitting which makes the `while` loop necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You had two errors:
- `i + 1` probably meant `i += 1`, then `i` musty be declared `global` so it can be modicied in the scope of the function.
- the Button command was `black()`, which is a call to the function black. What is needed is a reference to the function `black` (without the `()`)

> One thing to note: as remarked by @Sierra_Mountain_Tech, as it is, the user must first input an integer for the
>   tkinter app to start.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import random
import sys
import random

maxcount = int (input("How many times "))
i = 1

cats = Tk()
cats.wm_title("maxcount test")
cats.geometry("500x500")

def black():
    global i
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i >= 5:    # <-- changed from i == 5 at @Sierra_Mountain_Tech suggestion
            break

Button(cats, text="Start", command=black).grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(cats, text="How many times:").grid(row=0, column=0)    

cats.mainloop()
```

Comment: Also if you press start more than once the program will freeze. Change if `i == 5` to `if i >= 5`

Comment: One last thing you may want to add to your answer. The user is using `input` prior to the start of the tkinter app so the program will not open until they enter an integer in the console. They appear to be new to tkinter at least so this may be something they are not aware of.

Comment: Thank you for improving my answer.

Comment: The while loop is completely unnecessary. You're just looping until i is 5, so why not just set i to 5 and return?

Comment: This is a valid question that maybe the OP can answer @Brian. AFAIK, this could possibly be an artifact of creating a minimal example.